# How do I create a table with count of instances of an id before an event date that is individual to that id?

Tags: oracle, subquery

I am very new to SQL and have a relatively complex query to write, any help would be appreciated.

I have data with the following columns:

```
ORDER_ID
CUST_ID
ORDER_DATE
RETURNED(1/0)
```

I need a table with the following three columns:

- `CUST_ID`
- A column with the count of the number of orders a specific customer had before their FIRST returned order.
- A column with the count of number of orders a specific customer had after their FIRST returned order.

Each order has a unique id as does each customer, but there are many customers who had multiple orders at different dates. Not all customers had returned orders and I just need the counts for the customers who had a returned order (`RETURNED`=1).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do?

```
with only_returned as
  (select cust_id, 
          min(order_date) min_order_date
   from your_table
   where returned = 1
   group by cust_id
  )
select r.cust_id, 
       count(b.order_id) returned_before,
       count(a.order_id) returned_after
from only_returned r 
  join your_table b on b.cust_id = r.cust_id
                   and b.order_date < r.min_order_date
  join your_table a on a.cust_id = r.cust_id          
                   and a.order_date > r.min_order_date;
```

- `ONLY_RETURNED` CTE contains customers whose orders were returned; it also selects the first return order date
- then, join `only_returned` with `your_table`, twice:

  - once for orders placed before minimum return order date (the `b` alias)
  - once for orders placed after minimum return order date (the `a` alias)